# What does the output Object[...] in Firebug mean?

Tags: angularjs, firebug

I am currently logging an object in an AngularJS directive, particularly the parameters of the `link()` function of the directive. This is the part:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  console.log(attrs)
}
```

In the console I'll then see this logged:

```
Object[my-customer.ng-isolate-scope]
```

When I click the link to more information of the object, it switches from the *Console* panel to the *DOM* panel:

[image: *DOM* panel displaying <code>attrs</code> parameter of <code>link()</code> function]

So how to read that output? Is it an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug displays array-like objects like this:

```
Object[...]
```

Array-like objects are objects that can be iterated over like arrays, i.e. have indexes. I've created a [list of values](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Display_of_JavaScript_values_and_DOM_items) displayed within the *DOM* panel.

In this case it is an array-like object that contains the DOM node `my-customer.ng-isolate-scope`.